# How to fix IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django

I created UserProfile model and when i go to django admin and trying to create/change profile it throws an error *IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed*. I am new to djnago so I don’t understand why i'm getting this error.

users/models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 40, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'username', null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args=[str(self.slug)])


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, db_constraint=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'avatar', default = "empty_avatar.jpg", blank = True, null = True)
    description = models.TextField(default = '', null = True)
    recipe = models.ManyToManyField(Dish, blank = True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'user', null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Профиль'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Профили'

    @receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.userprofile.save()
```

recipe/models.py

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
```

I think it is something wrong with *ManyToManyField* but i don't know what

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username',)


class CustomUserForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username',)


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('avatar', 'description',)
```

views.py

```
def user_profile(request, slug):
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(slug = slug)
    profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(slug = request.user.slug)
    user_form = CustomUserChangeForm
    profile_form = UserProfileForm
    return render(request, template_name = 'users/profile.html', context = {'user': user, 'profile':profile, 'profile_form':profile_form})
```

This is the complete error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1660, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1540, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 246, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 266, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
[12/Aug/2021 18:16:10] "POST /admin/users/userprofile/4/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 131314
[12/Aug/2021 18:16:11] "GET /admin/users/userprofile/4/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17650
Internal Server Error: /admin/users/userprofile/4/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1660, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1540, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 246, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 266, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

**EDITED**
I added admin.py

```
CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'slug']
    list_filter = ['is_staff', 'is_active',]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields':('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')
        }),
    )

    search_fields = ('email', 'username')
    ordering = ('email',)


admin.site.register(UserProfile)
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've created super user before writing this code I guess. So your admin user haven't linked with any profile yet.

You can do this in three ways:

1. Recreate your superuser by `python3 manage.py createsuperuser`
2. Update your save method

   ```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance.userprofile.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
   ```
3. Drop db and migration files and migrate with new db.

Comment: Yes, I created a superuser before writing UserPtofile, but I already tried to delete the superuser and create it again and I still cannot change, delete or create the profile. Could it be that by creating a superuser before I wrote the code, I caused some errors in the database?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: If you do not have too much data in db, I would suggest you to delete old db and migrate and createsuper user with new db.